# get all but last occurrences of a pattern in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

Given the following patterns:

```
"profile[foreclosure_defenses_attributes][0][some_text]"
"something[something_else_attributes][0][hello_attributes][0][other_stuff]"
```

I am able to extract the last part using non-capturing groups:

```
var regex = /(?:\w+(\[\w+\]\[\d+\])+)(\[\w+\])/;
str = "profile[foreclosure_defenses_attributes][0][properties_attributes][0][other_stuff]";
match = regex.exec(str);
["profile[foreclosure_defenses_attributes][0][properties_attributes][0][other_stuff]", "[properties_attributes][0]", "[other_stuff]"]
```

However, I want to be able to get everything but the last part. In other words, everything but [some_text] or [other_stuff].

I cannot figure out how to do this with noncapturing groups. How else can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like?

```
 shorter, and matches from the back if you can have more of the [] items.

var regex = /(.*)(?:\[\w+\])$/;
var a = "something[something_else_attributes][0][hello_attributes][0][other_stuff11][other_stuff22][other_stuff33][other_stuff44]".match(regex)[1];
    a;
```

or using replace, though less performant.

```
 var regex = /(.*)(?:\[\w+\])$/;

 var a = "something[something_else_attributes][0][hello_attributes][0][other_stuff11][other_stuff22][other_stuff33][other_stuff44]".replace(regex, function(_,$1){ return $1});
     a;
```

Comment: Yeah this worked for me. Out of curiosity, why you use replace? I find exec to be more concise.

Comment: I updated to something shorter. The "match" usage was arbitrary as I was doing it in the command line, and just more comfortable to type.

Comment: Would you please remove the misused `replace` example? It will incur unnecessary performance hit, while the `match` method is as concise.

Comment: Sure. Updated per request.

Answer (score 0):

If those really are your strings:

```
var regex = /(.*)\[/;
```